# How to store a sparse list in python?

Tags: python

Now I have a dict object, where the key is a unique hashed id and the value is a length > 100 sparse list. I'd like to store this in plain text(e.g., csv/tsv/whatever that is not pickle.dump). Is there any good way to store this kind of sparse list?
For example:

```
d = {"a": [0,0,0, ..., 1,0], "b": [0.5,0,0, ...,0.5,0], "c":...}
```

The length of each list is exactly the same. I was thinking whether it's worth storing this kind of sparse list as index-value pair. But I'm not sure whether there is any package do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Hi @wwii, is there anything hard to understand for the question?

Comment: `... is not a python object).` In Python everything is an object.

Comment: Here I mean I do not want to use pickle.dump. Instead, I'd hope to find some methods that could store sparse list as readable file. Sorry for the confusion and it should be updated now.

Comment: Also plz let me know if you have any idea how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and practicing the examples in it - it will give you and idea of the tools Python has to offer - you will start getting ideas for solving your problem. Try some of the ideas out and if you get stuck, come back and ask.

Comment: JSON would do it for you.

Comment: What's your main objective? Are you just trying to save it to a file, or are you wanting to condense it down to something smaller?

Comment: @Rob Watts, exactly. I'd like to save space to avoid storing 0s.

Comment: You can try libsvm format http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file.html which doesn't store zeros.

Comment: @Mr.cysl then don't go for plain text. Plain text **is** the wrong format for floating point numbers – not only is it incredibly wasteful on space, you also get rounding errors. Your requirements "compact" is directly clashing with "plain text". Why do you think plain text is useful, anyway? You obviously don't want to preserve the "tabular" nature, anyway, so reading through your "condensed" plain text will be hard to understand, anyway.

Comment: @wwii, I'm sorry I do not think the official doc discusses anything about store sparse list. Please detail if you think there's any.

Comment: @Mr.cysl you are expected to read the second line of documentation of that link: *it does not store zero valued features hence is suitable for sparse dataset.*

Comment: @Marcus Müller, I kind of agree with you. If it could be a dump, are there any recommended packages/ways? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marcus Müller, but in that way I need to specify y(label), however, that's what I did not have.

Comment: Python offers tools that serialize data in multiple ways. Your task is to come up with an algorithm using one or more of those tools to serialize the data customized for your requirements and turn that algorithm into code..

Comment: @Mr.cysl simply use [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). Comes with serialization/deserialization. You could simply store your `a` to `z` as rows of a matrix and have a simply dict that maps letters to rows.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I will look at this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np   
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix,lil_matrix,save_npz,load_npz
a = {'a':[0,0,1,0],'b':[1,0,0,0],'c':[1,1,0,0]}
sparse1 = csr_matrix(np.array(a.values())) ## You can use lil_matirx as well
print sparse1
print sparse1.toarray()
save_npz('values.npz',sparse1)
np.save('keys.npy',np.array(a.keys()))
sparse3 = load_npz('values.npz')
print sparse3
print sparse3.toarray()
keys = np.load('keys.npy')
print keys

print dict(zip(keys,sparse3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than saving the 0s, you should transform the sparse list into a dictionary of the non-zero values. For example,

```
{'a':[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3]}
```

could become

```
{'a':{3:1, 6:2, 9:3}}
```

You could transform the lists easily enough with a dictionary comprehension:

```
compressed_data = {
    hashed_id: {
        index: value for index, value in enumerate(values) if value != 0
    } for hashed_id, values in original_data.items()
}
```

Then you could just save that dictionary to a file. After you load the compressed list from the file:

```
decompressed_data = {}
for hashed_id, values in loaded_data.items():
    decompressed_values = [0] * DATA_LENGTH
    for index, value in values.items():
        decompressed_values[index] = value
    decompressed_data[hashed_id] = decompressed_values
```

Comment: This is exactly I'm looking for!

Comment: I'd argue it's not – it does fulfill your spec of being a sparse matrix plain text format, but it still doesn't make sense to care about storage space and plaintextness at the same time. They are conflicting targets, and I think your problem is ill-posed in the first place. There have been *binary* sparse matrix formats at least as long as there's been FORTRAN. So, that's more than 40 years now. They are still used, for a reason, unlike sparse plain text files, which make little sense – sparsity only matters for large (in computer term large) matrices, and for these having plaintext doesn't…

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Alternatively to `{index: value for index, value in enumerate(values) if value != 0}` you can also write `dict(filter(itemgetter(1),enumerate(values)))` depending on your preferred style.