# How to fill a list with default arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class

How do i fill the list of entries with default elements when making a class, without putting anything in any of the positions?
For example.

```
MyClass([1,,3])
```

I would like for my class to understand that it is getting a `[1,0,3]` where `0` is the default argument.

Comment: That wouldn't have anything to do with default arguments since that's a list. There is no way to skip an element in a list literal, or to default an element of a list literal afaik.

Comment: Are you asking how to define a class such that an instance of the class can be provided with default arguments?

Comment: @itprorh66 Yes, that's it!

Comment: Since `[1,,3]` is invalid syntax you can't do that. You can use `[1, None, 3]` and then replace every `None` with a default value.

Comment: I think the closest you're going to be able to get is to ditch the `[]` literal syntax, and instead use keyword arguments directly to `__init__`. Then you can skip and element by simply not including it, and you can specify the default in the parameter list of `__init__`.

Comment: What about `l = [0] * 10`

Answer (score 1):

If the input might have large empty sections, it'd be easier to [use a dict as a faux sparse list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46757026/4518341).

```
def list_filler(dict_sparse, default=0):
    """Make a list out of a dict that acts as a faux sparse list."""
    top = max(dict_sparse)
    out = [dict_sparse.get(i, default) for i in range(top+1)]
    return out
```

Usage:

```
>>> list_filler({0: 1, 2: 3})
[1, 0, 3]
>>> list_filler({1: 'b', 7: 'h'}, '.')
['.', 'b', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'h']
```

Note that negative keys will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Python syntax allows default values for callables (including object creation), but only at the end of the parameters.

Example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x=1, y=2, z=3):
        ...
```

Then you can use defaults:

```
a = A()        # same as a = A(1, 2, 3)
b = A(4)       # same as b = A(4, 2, 3)
```

But this `c = A(5, , 6)` is a syntax error. If you want to use default parameter but not the last ones, you must name them:

```
c = A(5, c=6)  # same as c = A(5, 2, 6)
```

Comment: Hi Serge! My problem is that I know it work as you said but my problem is that I'm being asked to receive a "list of list" as one of the entries of my script (it is a matrix class which get the dimensions as the first two inputs, and as a third, the list of lists which are going to be the entries of it). Anyways thanks about the comment of syntax error, I didn't know it

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a class and include default values for terms in several ways.

```
class MyClass:
      def __init__(self, x=1, y=0, z=3):
            . . . . . . .
            . . . . . . .
```

Note:  In this case, the values, x, y, z are determined by their position so instantiating MyClass requires either all three values to be provided, or no values be provided.   This may not satisfy your needs.

Alternatively, you can:

```
class MyClass:
      def __init__(self, **args): 
            . . . . . . . 
            . . . . . . .
```

In this approach, **args is a list of Named arguments that may or may not be present.  If present, the initialization function will assign the corresponding variable the declared value, if not present the initialization function will take a default value.  the **args variable appears to the function as a dictionary of the form {"ParameterName1": val, "ParameterName2: val,. . . . }